# Replace words in data frame using list of words in another data frame in R

Tags: r

I am trying to convert a large R data frame (3 million rows of patients by 400 columns of diagnoses), from short description e.g., “ESSENTIAL HYPERTENSION, BENIGN” to the description ICD code e.g., “I10”. The short descriptions are in a data frame “DATA” and also include patient ID and age columns that I do not want changed. The data frame “Dictionary” is my list of words containing the short description and associated ICD code. There are over 20k combinations of descriptions and ICD codes in the actual dictionary list. To make the problem reproducible I have included code that recreates small samples of my larger DATA and Dictionary data frames.

DATA Sample

```
PAT_ID <- c(1,2,3)

DX_1 <- c('OTHER&UNSPECIFIED HYPERLIPIDEMIA','NA','ESSENTIAL HYPERTENSION, BENIGN' )

DX_AGE_1 <- c(66,68,75)

DX_2 <- c('ESSENTIAL HYPERTENSION, BENIGN','SPECIAL SCR MALIG NEOPLASM PROS','NA' )

DX_AGE_2 <- c(67,69,77)

DATA <- data.frame(PAT_ID, DX_1, DX_AGE_1,DX_2,DX_AGE_2)
```

Dictionary Sample

```
From <- c('OTHER&UNSPECIFIED HYPERLIPIDEMIA','ESSENTIAL HYPERTENSION, BENIGN','SPECIAL SCR MALIG NEOPLASM PROS')

To <- c('E784', 'I10', 'Z125')
    
Dictionary <- data.frame(From, To)
```

My Desired output would look like the output of this code

```
PAT_ID <- c(1,2,3)
DX_1 <- c('E784','NA','I10' )
DX_AGE_1 <- c(66,68,75)
DX_2 <- c('I10','Z125','NA' )
DX_AGE_2 <- c(67,69,77)
OUTPUT <- data.frame(PAT_ID, DX_1, DX_AGE_1,DX_2,DX_AGE_2)
```

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Using Base R, you could do:

```
vec <- do.call(setNames,rev(unname(Dictionary)))
rapply(DATA, function(x)vec[x],'character', how= 'replace')

  PAT_ID DX_1 DX_AGE_1 DX_2 DX_AGE_2
1      1 E784       66  I10       67
2      2 <NA>       68 Z125       69
3      3  I10       75 <NA>       77
```

Also you could use `str_replace_all` from `stringr`:

```
setNames(type.convert(data.frame(
         array(str_replace_all(as.matrix(DATA), vec), dim(DATA)))), names(DATA))
  PAT_ID DX_1 DX_AGE_1 DX_2 DX_AGE_2
1      1 E784       66  I10       67
2      2 <NA>       68 Z125       69
3      3  I10       75 <NA>       77
```